# GridDB TXN_SERVICE_START_FAILED Error: How to Check and Address Insufficient Memory?

Tags: memory, nosql, wsl-2, griddb

I'm facing an issue with GridDB where I'm encountering the "TXN_SERVICE_START_FAILED" error, indicating a failure to start the transaction service. The error message suggests that memory may be insufficient.

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

I've done some research and found a recommendation to check if there is sufficient memory space in the system. My question is, how do I go about checking the available memory in the system?

Specifically:

1. What commands or tools can I use to check the current memory usage on my system?
2. How can I interpret the results to determine if memory is indeed insufficient for GridDB to start the transaction service?

If anyone has encountered the "TXN_SERVICE_START_FAILED" error in the context of GridDB or has insights into addressing memory-related issues, your guidance would be greatly appreciated.